# Display Custom Options from Simple Product into Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am creating a simple test product in magento and trying to add some custom attributes for variants. Unfortunatly these are not showing up in the front end.

So I'm pretty sure it's a theme issue here...

When I add a custom product option such as a drop down, the Add to Cart button vanished and can no longer be purchased... as well as now showing the dropdown.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Is there a directory to look this stuff up in?

I've added some photos in case my description wasn't clear enough

Thanks

[image: Photo of Front End when custom option added]

[image: Photo of Back End when custom option added]

Answer (score 0):

1. Try clearing your caches
2. Check the inventory tab, if product is saleable on frontend (in stock and has qty)
3. check /var/log/ and /var/report for errors
4. calling isSaleable() on the product object can direct you as well (this check is also in product actions template where the add to cart button is rendered)

Just a note but if you have product variants (say size) you probably want to use [configurable products](http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/configurable-products) instead of custom options

Answer (score 0):

I have had same issue in my new magento 1.9

I just clean all caches from var/cache

Also clean your cache from magento admin.